# React-Native - Path to local Files

Tags: file, react-native, ffmpeg, local

my question is about react-native 0.60+ and about local files.

My App has the followed folder structure:

- App.js
- android
- ios
- node_modules
- src

  - components
  - views
  - assets
  - images

    - myImage.png

Now, i want to get the path from myImage.png.
I want to add an Watermark to a Video. The Watermark to add, is the myImage.png. For that issue i use the ffmpeg-Library.

But how can i access to these files? What is the Path of these files?
i have tried it with React-Native-Filesystem (RNFS), but with no solutions.

Every time a get: Directory or File not exists

FFMPEG Cmd:

`const ffmpegWatermarkCommand = '-i '
+ RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath+ '/videos/myVideo.mp4 '
+ "-i [Path to Local Watermark]/myImage.jpg '
+ '-filter_complex "overlay=10:10" '
+ RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + '/videos/outVideomp4';`

I hope someone has an solution for me. Thanks

Comment: I have same problem 3 years later.  Did you find a solution ? everybody recommend using react-native-fs but nobody say what paths we should use to reference local asset files....

Answer (score 2):

For IOS, you have to add your asset in a "Resources" folder in XCode

[image]

Now, clean and rebuild everything (Xcode Project + Metro)

And then use RNFS like this :

```
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';
const path = `${RNFS.MainBundlePath}/intro.mov`
```

NB : You can see what is in your app directory with this code :

```
RNFS.readDir(RNFS.MainBundlePath)
  .then(result => {
    console.log('GOT RESULT', result);
    // stat the first file
    return Promise.all([RNFS.stat(result[0].path), result[0].path]);
  })
  .then(statResult => {
    if (statResult[0].isFile()) {
      // if we have a file, read it
      return RNFS.readFile(statResult[1], 'utf8');
    }
    return 'no file';
  })
  .then(contents => {
    console.log(contents);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err.message, err.code);
  });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use 'require' keyword for assets to be bundled with app.
As described here:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images

Add a images.js file just for requiring images (create it anywhere just update the path accordingly)

```
const images = {
  myImage: require("./images/myImage.png")
}
```

Then provide the path relative to the file that you are currently setting the ffmpegWatermarkCommand

```
const ffmpegWatermarkCommand = '-i '
+ RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath+ '/videos/myVideo.mp4 '
+ "-i ../images/myImage.jpg '
+ '-filter_complex "overlay=10:10" '
+ RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + '/videos/outVideomp4';
```

Comment: I know, that I must use 'require' for the <Image> Tag. But I need the path of the image for ffmpeg. I can't use require in ffmpeg. Or can I?

Comment: can you post your code ?    myImage.png will not be bundled w/o 'require'

Comment: ffmpeg Command:

`const ffmpegWatermarkCommand = '-i '
                + RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath+ '/videos/myVideo.mp4 '
                + "-i [Path to Local Watermark]/myImage.jpg '
                + '-filter_complex "overlay=10:10" '
                // -y Override existing Output
                + RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + '/videos/outVideomp4';`

I cannot use require there. (I also updated my first post)

Comment: Thanks for answer me. But it doesnt work. Now, i have an directory under /assets/images/images.js. In the data i have a const, that requires the image like in your example. If i use the path in my ffmpeg Command like "../assets/images/image/watermark.png" then i get the error "../assets/images/images/watermark.png: No such file or directory". I know that doesnt work, but there is no image under images/waternark.png..

I hope u can help me, again :P

please let me know, if you need code. I done it like in your answer

Comment: before  const ffmpegWatermarkCommand  , you will need to call the images code , something like :  const myImage = images['myImage']

Comment: i know what you mean, but i cant use ../images/myImage.png in the ffmpeg command. If i call const watermark = require(..); before the command, there is no reference to the watermark in the ffmpeg command..

in your example you do ../images/myImage.jpg in the ffmpeg command. but what does that have to do with the const? There is no connection or do I understand something wrong? Is your example correct? I post the code my code as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach, without the need for extra libraries, is to just convert `myImage.jpg` to a base64 string and use the data uri as the the input.

So it would look something like this

```
const watermarkImg = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,iVBORw0KGgo...'

const ffmpegWatermarkCommand = '-i '
+ RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + '/videos/myVideo.mp4 '
+ '-i ' + watermarkImg + ' '
+ '-filter_complex "overlay=10:10" '
+ RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + '/videos/outVideo.mp4';
```